# How to disable touch for whole screen (Fragment + BottomNavigation) whille fetching data from database?

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, kotlin

I have a bottomnavigation activity with 3 frargments(menu). But if we click a button (including the bottomnavigation button) while the app is still fetching the data, the app will crash.

I've tried to search on google and stackoverflow about this problem. But it's only make the fragment untouchable, not both with the bottomnavigation.

MainActivity.kt

```
private val onNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.navigation_home -> {
            replaceFragment(HomeFragment())
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_account -> {
            replaceFragment(AccountFragment())
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_other -> {
            replaceFragment(OtherFragment())
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
    }
    false
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    nav_view.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    replaceFragment(HomeFragment())
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().isAutoInitEnabled = true
}

private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
```

HomeFragment.kt

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    lrMath.setOnClickListener {
        val matematikaIntent = Intent(requireActivity(), MathActivity::class.java)
        requireActivity().startActivity(matematikaIntent)
    }
    fetchUser()
}
.
.
.
private fun fetchUser() {
    val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users")


    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            p0.children.forEach {
                val user = it.getValue(User::class.java)

                if (user != null && uid == user.uid) {
                    textGreetings = "Hi " + user.name + ","

                    Picasso.get().load(user.profileImageUrl).into(profile_button)
                    greetings_textview.text = textGreetings
                    flag = 1
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        }
    }
    )
}
```

I want to make all the view/screen untouchable until the data fetched. So there'll be no crash.

Comment: In such cases  we usually go for progress bar . Or you take  a view overlay and makes it visibility gone , once your downloading is done .

Answer (score 2):

You can block the touch event for the activity:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

And to enable it again:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

Just create an interface between fragment and the activity to call the methods to enable/disable it.

Comment: how do I create the interface between the fragment an the activity?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Progress bar(Loader) instead of disabling Touch Event. Display Progress Bar is best approach for fetching data.

Here is example,

**CustomDialog.java**

```
public class CustomDialog {

public static Dialog loadDialog = null;

public static void showLoader(Activity context) {

    if (loadDialog != null) {
        if (loadDialog.isShowing())
            loadDialog.dismiss();
    }
    loadDialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.TransparentDialogTheme);
    loadDialog.setContentView(R.layout.loader);
    loadDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    loadDialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (!loadDialog.isShowing()) {
        loadDialog.show();
    }
}

public static void hideLoader() {
    if (loadDialog != null && loadDialog.isShowing())
        loadDialog.dismiss();
}
```

}

**TransparentDialogTheme**

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/bg_progress" />
```

**bg_progress**

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toDegrees="360">
<shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="12"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <size
        android:width="200dp"
        android:height="200dp" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:centerColor="@color/colorLightRed"
        android:endColor="@color/colorLightRed"
        android:startColor="@color/colorDarkRed"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do that is with progress bar (Loading ..) 
until the app finished the data **OR**
you have to use service in background .
have a look on this example for Progress bar [here](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-progressbar-with-examples)
hope that helped you